# Java: Could you give me a hand with an algorithm about processing a String?

Tags: java, json, string, algorithm

I am currently working in a really old system (early 2000's) that in the future will be migrated but right now cannot be modified.

This system communicates using socket connection and sending the message in the next format: "CALLNAME|FieldName~Value|FieldName~Value|...". So for example, it could be "CallToPaymentModule|Name~Charles|Cost~3|..."

I would have intercept this message and map it into an object where the variables are the "FieldName" and their value is the "Value".

The only solution I was able to perform at the moment was to transform into a JSON using regular expressions and then map into an object, but probably there is a faster solution.

Does someone have anything in mind?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: If you have particular performance requirements, please state them. If you just want commentary on your code and how to make it subjectively "better", please post your code on codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Performance is really relevant, that's why I would like to see if there is any different approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (often more efficient and precise) alternative to regular expressions is *parsing*. This is a standard topic in computer science. Fortunately, it looks like your data has a very simple format which should be easy to write a parser for. You can either write a parser by hand, which would basically manually loop over the characters in the string and decide what to do, or something like that, or you can use a parser generator like Antlr which will generate a parser class for you from a grammar specification.